# IOC container assembly scanning performance

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, autofac

Is convention based assembly scanning good idea? Currently I have something like

```
foreach(var type in assembly)
{
    if(isRepository(type))
        registerAsRepository(type);
}
```

This takes more than 1 second at startup. I wonder if it wouldn't be better to just register all types by hand, and implement some kind of "registration testing" in tests rather than at doing it at runtime?

Comment: Please read [this](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/11/06/WhentouseaDIContainer/) and [this](https://simpleinjector.org/blog/2015/12/when-should-you-use-a-container/).

Comment: Good point for convention. However I dislike fact that conventions have to process all types in all assemblies at runtime, and I cannot easly precompute it.

Also it gets harder when conventions change, for instance you have full text search IQueryHandler that works on mysql, but suddenly You have sphinx service that does exacly same thing. Or You want swap services based on config. Or you have two sets of IQueryHandler, one for oracle and another one for mysql (in one assembly). What then? OOTB autofac registrars won't handle that conventions.

Comment: I would advice not using a container at all. A container is an optional tool. It gets really powerful when you do convention over configuration and batch-registration. If your application is small enough, doing [Pure DI](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/) might be much more valuable.

Comment: "This takes more than 1 second at startup.". Did you test this in production (in release mode) as well? And do you only scan your application assemblies or do you scan ALL loaded assemblies (including System.* assemblies)?

Comment: "Did you test this in production" - yes. I am checking only MyCompany.* Types. At start I really enjoyed DI, but then things like "let's support oracle database and webservice in parallel to mysql" or "let's do it differently for that client" changed my conventions into wild monsters, and I wanted to ask if it is best option before I keep going in that direction. My app is huge ecommerce application with cms, supporting multiple catalogues, databases, or third party storage/financial systems etc, so I'd say it's kinda huge.

Comment: Most containers allow you to replace a made registration after it was made. This allows you to do common batch-registration and swap out a few specific implementations. My personal preference is to only use batch-registration on generic types like `IQueryHandler<T, R>` and `ICommandHandler<T>`. These generic abstractions span 80% to 95% of the components in my system, which leaves just a few components that require hand-wiring. This gives me full flexibility, because the hand-wired types are usually the ones that might need swapping out (for different configuration settings or strategies e.g.)

Comment: That's what I started with, but then it got hardcore, for example:

    ```- register all components from oracle db (skip mysql)
    - replace registration with components from sphinx but one (not known at compile time) ```

To achive this I cannot do something like:

    ```- add oracle conventions
    - add sphinx conventions
    - revert back one component to mysql (becasue idk if it was mysql or oracle component)```

So I have 3 implementations of IQueryHandler<FullTextProductSearch, ProductList>.

Comment: Would it work if you place the group of swappable components into a separate assembly? In that case you would only have to swap out that assembly for a different one during batch registration. You can postfix them with .Oracle.dll and .MySql.dll

Answer (score -1):

I love this question. It's so simple yet it touches so many aspects of the problem space.

Like many things in software (IoC) containers aren't a panacea. They trade a level of runtime performance for a level of runtime flexibility and development time productivity.

Also like all tools, they work best when used properly. And since containers manage lifecycle of objects in your application, the *properly* part here refers to the structure of your app.

Now, it's hard to give specific advice having no details, so I'll be fairly generic.

First, the 1s overhead of scanning a single assembly is highly suspicious on anything resembling modern hardware. It's hard to judge from the pseudocode you posted where the issue in your real code might be, but there clearly is an issue and it's most likely not your container. I would also recommend not doing this type of low level scanning yourself and instead rely in the high level API that your container gives you. It's usually going to be more efficient and readable than any custom code like this.

Then there's the question of architecture. Containers are a sharp tool and give you a range of options despite the simplicity of their API. All the examples you give in the comments can be easily handled with a combination of by-convention registration, explicit type registration and some configuration. I would refer you to the documentation of your container of choice about the specifics but it's a standard scenario and all mature containers deal with it very well and with more than acceptable performance.

Comment: Thank You for answer. Apparently that 1 s of startup time is just cost of the di, I am just sad that new project starts slower than old one ;).

Could you give me example of such registration by convention where you want to register handlers only for MySql and not for Oracle in one assembly? (I mean that they differ only by dependencies)